# How do I track and reuse small projects I've written across many large projects I'm writing?

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code

I have written a single, monolithic project (let's call it **Monolith.py**) over the course of about 3 years in python. During that time I have created a lot of large and small utilities that would be useful in other projects.

Here are a couple simple examples:

- **Color.py**: A small script that easily allows me to essentially colorize text. I use this a lot for print().
- **OExplorer.py**: A larger script that is a CLI object explorer that I can use to causally browse classes and objects interactively.

Stuff like that. There's probably 20 of them, mostly modules. They are all under constant development.

My question is, what is the best way to use those in another project and keeping everything up to date?

I am using visual studio code and I use it to handle all my git stuff. I'm guessing there's a way to like nested git folders? I'm worried about screwing up my main repo.

I also do not want to separate out these projects into their own vscode workspace. It is better if they are left where they are. I also do not want to pull in all the code from the monolith for another project, that would be silly.

I think there is a simple git solution here. I would appreciate it if someone can give me some direction here and hand hold a bit, git is clearly not my strong suit.

Comment: Put these utilities in a single git repository and add the repository as a submodule of other repositories. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: I do not want to add all of them each time, I would like to add them separately as needed. How do I do that? Just create multiple submodules? Also, what exactly is a submodule?

Comment: A submodule is a nested repository. It's a bit like a plugin. You can plug a git repository as a submodule into another repository as needed. There are many tutorials about submodules you can find online.